# how add class active for parent when child router link clicked in angular 5

Tags: angular

hi i am having the following html code

```
    <li class="" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/home']">my first tab</a></li>


        <li [class.active]="rla?.isActive"  routerLinkActive="active"><a class="pointer">my second tab</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="" #rla="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active" ><a [routerLink]="['/myFirstLink','rock']">Past</a></li>
                        <li class="" #rla="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active" ><a [routerLink]="['/myFirstLink','aj']">Upcoming</a></li>
                    </ul> 

     </li>
</li>
```

and path is

```
{
        path: "myFirstLink/:param",
        loadChildren: ".....
}
```

so how to add class active for my second tab when we clicked myFirstLink with out using jquery?, my code is not working

Comment: Means when I click children router line i.e rock and AJ. Indeed to add class called active to my parent li tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`routerLinkActive` will work only if you try to route any component - i dont see you're trying to route to any component by clicking **second tab** so remove the `routerLinkActive` from it

Dynamically add active to the second tab when you click the child tabs of it - I will tell you a solution to add dynamically - you need to know when the child tabs are clicked so bind a `(click)` event to it

```
`<li routerLinkActive="active" >
   <a [routerLink]="['/myFirstLink','rock']" (click)='addClass = true'>Past</a>
</li>
<li routerLinkActive="active">
   <a [routerLink]="['/myFirstLink','aj']" (click)='addClass = true'>Upcoming</a>
</li>`
```

`addClass` will be your property in your `component.ts` with value `false` and when the child component is clicked it will be come true now finally add this property to your parent tab

```
<li [class.active]="addClass"><a class="pointer">my second tab</a>
```

Hope this will work - change the `addClass` property to false if it not selected - not a officially way to work, but seems like a workaround.

Happy Coding !!

Comment: Actually my second tab like is pop up, so I cannot put router to parent li.so when click on home router now my both first tab and second is active  I need to activate only one tab at a time

Comment: wha tif we do page refresh

Comment: Just bind the same click function to the first tab as false`<a [routerLink]="['/home']" (click)='addClass = false'>my first tab</a>` it will deactivate all the child active classes

Comment: When you refresh - you can read the route from your ts and change the state to true or false - inject `ActivatedRoute` in your component constructor and read the url like this `this._activateRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.path`in your `onInit`

Answer (score 0):

So if you need set active to parent when child is active, 
`[routerLink]="['/home']"` change to `[routerLink]="['/myFirstLink']"`